# device not connecting mobile device to device through bluetooth low energy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

How to communicate mobile device with `BLE` when an application installs in mobile and trying to get other mobile device battery information where ScanCallback does not return any information on searching `BLE device`.

```
  private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
 //            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
             Log.e("scaning result"," :"+result.getDevice().getName());
             bluetoothDevice = result.getDevice();
             deviceAddress.setText(bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
             deviceName.setText(bluetoothDevice.getName());
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }

         @Override
         public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
             super.onBatchScanResults(results);
         }

         @Override
         public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
             super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
             Log.d(TAG, "Scanning Failed " + errorCode);
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }
     };
```

Comment: What is your question here? It rather seems you are just complaining that the advertising data of some particular device doesn't include battery information?